# If file and directory exists

Tags: python

I am running into an issue where I try to move the file from source to destination. The script works the first time but when I run it again and if the file/directory exists; it throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fela/Downloads/script.py", line 118, in save_pics
    os.mkdir(dst_pics)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/Users/dela/Downloads/Dest/Pictures/'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fela/Downloads/script.py", line 385, in <module>
    save_pics(msg, user_name)
  File "/Users/fela/Downloads/script.py", line 120, in save_pics
    shutil.move(png, dst_pics)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 542, in move
    raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path '/Users/fela/Downloads/Dest/Pictures/image001.png' already exists
```

Here is my code:

```
src = /Users/fela/Downloads/Source
dst_pics = /Users/fela/Downloads/Dest/Pictures

    for png in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, "*.png")):
        if os.path.isfile(png):
            try:
                os.mkdir(dst_pics)
            except:
                shutil.move(png, dst_pics)
                continue

    for jpg in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, "*.[jJ][pP][gG]")):
        if os.path.isfile(jpg):
            try:
                shutil.move(jpg, dst_pics)
            except:
                continue
```

Comment: What's the question? Is the error message not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend making the directory *once*, outside the loop. This will simplify your code a bit.

```
import os

src = '/Users/fela/Downloads/Source'
dst_pics = '/Users/fela/Downloads/Dest/Pictures'

try:
    os.mkdir(dst_pics) # will create the directory only if it does not exist
except FileExistsError:
    pass

for png in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, "*.png")):
    if os.path.isfile(png):
        shutil.move(png, dst_pics)

for jpg in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, "*.[jJ][pP][gG]")):
    if os.path.isfile(jpg):
        shutil.move(jpg, dst_pics)
```

Comment: It gives me the same error
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 542, in move
    raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path '/Users/fela/Downloads/Dest/Pictures/image001.png' already exists

Comment: @SarahHastings Please relook very carefully at how you call `save_pics(msg, user_name)`. Print out those lines. Look at what Src and Dst actually are.

Comment: I tried changing it to save_attachments(msg, dst_pics) but it throws the same error message
if “Pictures” not in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    os.mkdir(“Pictures”)

for msg in generate_mail_messages(resumeFile):
    save_attachments(msg, “Pictures”)

Comment: @SarahHastings Your [mcve] is not the same as the code you are running. Please, tell me _how you are calling your functions_, and what are the strings being passed. I cannot help you otherwise...

Comment: Sarah, you seem to have marked my answer. Did it solve your problem?

Comment: It hasn't solved the issue yet but gave me a direction where to go and how to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, part of the problem you are having is that os.mkdir() requires a string or a reference to one. (Which as I just said should have ' ' or " " around it)

@ Coldspeed beat me to this question - again.

```
dist_pics = '/Users/fela/Downloads/Dest/Pictures'
```

And then reference it.Not too tricky and follow @Coldspeed for the rest of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, the alternative pointed out in the other answer of creating the directory outside the loop, and passing on any exception (e.g directory already exists), would be the best approach.

But, if you need to create the directory inside the loop for some reason, add code to check if your directory already exists before attempting to create it.

For example

```
for png in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, "*.png")):
    if not os.path.isdir(dst_pics):
        os.mkdir(dst_pics)
    if os.path.isfile(png):
        shutil.move(png, dst_pics)
```

The reason you need to do this is `os.mkdir` will raise an exception if the directory already exists. It is designed to do so.

The only reason I could see you would need to do something like this is if, for some reason , you wanted to move different files to different directories (from some data structure) based on some additional criterion in a loop. That's probably beyond the scope of the question.